# Combine/Concatenate Two Datasets

Tags: einstein-analytics

I would like to combine/concatenate two datasets that don't have any key/field relationship. Attached to this post are the example and the result format. Is this possible? If yes, how can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to do that?

Within the dasboard, then use the union command to combine the datasets.

To create a new dataset, which then can be used in multiple dashboards/lenses create a dataflow and use an append node.